# Not null validation error on a property that shouldn't exist

Tags: sequelize.js

I am writing unit tests for a node server that uses Sequelize. Upon insert of some fake data I am receiving the error

```
SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: QuestionId cannot be null
```

**Note the case: Capital Q on `QuestionId`**

Unit test:

```ts
describe('answerQuestion', () => {
    it('should insert an answer and get the next question', (done) => {
        Survey.DBModel.create({lookType: 0}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
            Question.DBModel.create({type: 0, text: 'Test question'}, {logging: false}).then(q1 => {
                Question.DBModel.create({type: 1, text: 'Next question'}, {logging: false}).then(q2 => {
                    console.log('before');
                    QuestionOption.DBModel.create({text: 'Test option', questionId: 1, nextQuestionId: 2}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
                        console.log('after');
                        Survey.answerQuestion(1, 1, 1).then(question => {
                            question.should.have.property('id');
                        }, done);
                    }, done);
                }, done);
            }, done);
        }, done);
    });
});
```

The console outputs 'before' but errors before it reaches 'after'

question.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Question = sequelize.define('Question', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    type: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    text: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    nextQuestionId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.Question.belongsTo(models.Question, {as: 'nextQuestion', foreignKey: {field: 'nextQuestionId', allowNull: true}});
        models.Question.hasMany(models.Answer, {as: 'answers', foreignKey: {field: 'questionId', allowNull: false}});
        models.Question.hasMany(models.QuestionOption, {as: 'options', foreignKey: {field: 'questionId', allowNull: false}});
        models.Question.hasMany(models.QuestionOption, {as: 'referrers', foreignKey: {field: 'nextQuestionId', allowNull: true}});
      }
    }
  });
  return Question;
};
```

questionoption.js

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var QuestionOption = sequelize.define('QuestionOption', {
    id: {
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    questionId: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    text: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    nextQuestionId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        models.QuestionOption.belongsTo(models.Question, {as: 'question', foreignKey: {field: 'questionId', allowNull: false}});
        models.QuestionOption.belongsTo(models.Question, {as: 'nextQuestion', foreignKey: {field: 'nextQuestionId', allowNull: true}});
      }
    }
  });
  return QuestionOption;
};
```

These models are pretty tightly coupled together and have self-referential joins and all sort of other mayhem. All other models I feel are non-relevant to this, but can be provided if needed.

Executing SQL on the SQLite database directly, in the same order and with the same properties as the create statements above does not throw an exception, and through much testing it is clear that Sequelize does not attempt to run the create statement for `QuestionOption`. It errors before generating the SQL to be run.

Some strange behavior is that the associations are meticulously defined in the models and all of them have a *lower case* `q` for `questionId` in their definitions. All associations also have a reverse association defined, so Sequelize shouldn't be trying to create names for properties.

All tables are dropped and recreated before each test (successfully).

Adding to the evidence that something weird is going on is if I remove the `questionId: 1` from the create statement for QuestionOption, then the error becomes

```
SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: questionId cannot be null, 
notNull Violation: QuestionId cannot be null
```

Note the casing of the two, one is lower (the one I removed) and one is upper.

Next suspect is the `nextQuestionId` association, but it has been defined in the model, and each side of the association as `allowNull: true` *and* I have provided it in the create statement.

I am purely baffled at this behavior and questioning if this perhaps is a bug in sequelize, though I would need to confirm this before falsely reporting it as such.

Other information that perhaps could be useful is:

- Tests are run using the command `NODE_ENV=test mocha`
- Database creation for tests is automatic using `sync` (code below)
- All other tests pass, but this is the only one using QuestionOption in the test.
- The method I am attempting to test works "in production" (running locally in dev with the client connected)
- Database schema has been verified with a SQLite GUI and all columns are appropriate (No `QuestionId` field in any table with a capital Q)

Database creation for tests

```ts
beforeEach((done) => {
    Survey.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
        Question.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
            Answer.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
                QuestionOption.DBModel.sync({force: true, logging: false}).then(() => {
                    done();
                }, done);
            }, done);
        }, done);
    }, done);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging around for the answer and creating a test repro. It turns out that this is a known issue with Sequelize. The solution, or more a dirty workaround, is to add the apparent "missing" property and then the query will work and it will throw out the value assigned to the ghost property.

```ts
describe('answerQuestion', () => {
    it('should insert an answer and get the next question', (done) => {
        Survey.DBModel.create({lookType: 0}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
            Question.DBModel.create({type: 0, text: 'Test question'}, {logging: false}).then(q1 => {
                Question.DBModel.create({type: 1, text: 'Next question'}, {logging: false}).then(q2 => {
                    QuestionOption.DBModel.create({
                        text: 'Test option', 
                        questionId: 1,
                        QuestionId: 1, <------ Workaround
                        nextQuestionId: 2}, {logging: false}).then(() => {
                        Survey.answerQuestion(1, 1, 1).then(question => {
                            question.should.have.property('id');
                        }, done);
                    }, done);
                }, done);
            }, done);
        }, done);
    });
});
```

The known issue can be found [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4708)

Test repro with this issue [here](https://github.com/SnareChops/sequelize-issue-repro) *(will remove link if changes)*

Hope this helps anyone else with this issue. I do wish that this was at least documented as a known issue in their documentation...